# Product items available

Tags: magento-enterprise

Hi is there magento extension that is free where customer can see how many items available to purchase a product?

Example on a product it will say

"In Stock"
"3 items left"

Comment: No exact extension is available as per your need. But, you can edit frontend product view and list phtml files (theme files) to fetch the stock quantity and show it for customers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an extension for that. Magento by default support this functionality. You just need to make below settings from the admin.

`Goto System>>Configuration>>Catalog>>Inventory>>Product Options`.

Check the screenshot for that

[image]

Here you can mention the threshold qty of product from where it starts displaying Only X qty left.

To change the text ie: Say `In Stock: 3 Items Left` You will have to make changes in the template file.

```
Goto: app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/cataloginventory/stockqty/composite.phtml
```

Make the appropriate changes over here.